# Firebase Realtime Database not writing from Android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem with Firebase Database.

**Scenario:**

I have an Android Application and Firebase project. They are linked in the console and I wish to write data from an application to Firebase. Initial setup of Firebase is made and I have a click listener, in the app, and once it is pressed the following code is executed:

```
private boolean value = true;
......
onClick(...) {
    value = !value;
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("info");
    ref.child("user").child("name").child("settings").setValue(value);
}
```

In my point of view, the expecting result would be a value change, for "/user/name/settings/" from true to false and vise versa.

**Problem:**

Here comes the issue. On the first app start, data is successfully sent to Firebase and value is changed (from true to false or vise versa). Then no matter how many times I press the button, nothing happens. I tried to kill the app, start it again and so on, but nothing. In order to write something in the "realtime" database I must uninstall the app and deployed it again to phone.

I tried to log something from click listener code and everything is executed right and values are exactly as supposed to be. Tried to add onSuccess, onFailure and onComplete callbacks.... nothing is even fired.

I'm using the latest version of libraries (11.2), I have an internet permission in manifest, phone is connected and it has internet.

To monitor data change I'm using Firebase console.

To be honest.....I'm really pissed off of the service :(

**Update (Answer):**

Of course problem was up to me... In one of my root fragment classes I have the following OLD code and it was causing troubles:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when `onClick()` method is triggered, you are setting the value of your boolean `value` field to `false`. This means that there will be no change in your Firbease database because the `value` is always the same.

To solve this, you need to change the logic of your code using an `if statement`.

```
onClick(...) {
    if(value) {
        //some code
    } else {
        //other code
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I'm not settings value always to false. First time it comes false, but next time it becomes true again and so on

Comment: Yes you are setting it always to false. First time when you declare `private boolean value = true` is set to true, and then every time you click the button is set to false. That's why i suggested  you to change the logic. When you update in Firebase o value which is the same as before nothing happens.

Comment: Yes and I have update the question with solution. In short...my mistake :)